# Prove that the ideal $M$ = $(x+2)F[x] + (x^2+8x+16)F[x]$ gives $F[x]$

Tags: linear-algebra

I claim that it suffices to show $M$ contains $f\in{F[x]}$, where $degf = n$ is any positive integer since M is a subspace, so by taking all linear combinations of f, one can get any polynomial with degree $n$. Is this correct, and is there a more mathematical way to express this?

Comment: That would give a proof but is very very complicated. Why not just show $4\in M$?

Comment: $$  \left(   x^{2}  + 8 x  + 16 \right)  =  \left(   x  + 2 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  + 6 \right) } +  \left( 4  \right)  $$   $$  \left(   x^{2}  + 8 x  + 16 \right)  \left( \frac{ 1}{4 } \right)  -  \left(   x  + 2 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x  + 6 }{ 4 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$  When $2 \neq 0$ we also have $4 \neq 0,$ so it has a multiplicative inverse in the field

Comment: So, is it the case that if we can show that for any $a\in{F}$, if  $a\in{M}$, then  $1\in{M}$ and from here it follows $M=F[x]$?